# Passed prop from child to parent not working (React)

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have child component with `<form>`  Value from input. Needs to be passed and rendered in parent component.   has `onSubmit` method which works in child, but doesn't seem to work in parent component. 
What is wrong here?

I am trying to render value of `<input>`(child) in `<h1>`(parrent).

Child.js

```
   state = {
     title : ''
   }
  onSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.props.textChange(this.state.title);
    this.setState({ title: '' });
  };

   onChange = (e) => this.setState({ title: e.target.value });


  render() {
    return (
      <div>
      <form 
        onSubmit={this.props.onSubmit}>
        <input 
          type="text" 
          name="title"
          placeholder="your tex here..."
          value={this.state.title}
          onChange={this.onChange}
        />

        <input 
        type="submit"
        value ="Submit"
        />
        </form>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
export default Text
```

Parent.js

```
class App extends Component {
  state = {
    colors: [],
    text: 'title'
  };

textChange = (title) => {
  console.log(title);
  this.setState({ text: title });
}

 return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1 className="title">{this.state.text}</h1>
      <Text textChange={this.textChange}/>
    </div>
```

Comment: change `{this.props.onSubmit}` to `{this.onSubmit}`

Comment: This seems like a weird way to do things. Do you want both components to have text in state? It would be more idiomatic to have text in parent and pass it down.

Comment: @Colin It is a task that I have to do like it. I've got directions how to do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

props are used to access parent method/values

change `{this.props.onSubmit}` to `{this.onSubmit}`as onSubmit is a method of the child

Answer (score 1):

Remove `props` from `onSubmit={this.props.onSubmit}`. Props are used to access data from the parent. In this case, the `onSubmit` function is local to the `Child.js` file, not the `Parent.js` file.

```
state = {
  title: ''
}
onSubmit = (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  this.props.textChange(this.state.title);
  this.setState({
    title: ''
  });
};

onChange = (e) => this.setState({
  title: e.target.value
});


render() {
  return ( <
    div >
    <
    form onSubmit = {
      this.onSubmit // REMOVED .props
    } >
    <
    input type = "text"
    name = "title"
    placeholder = "your tex here..."
    value = {
      this.state.title
    }
    onChange = {
      this.onChange
    }
    />

    <
    input type = "submit"
    value = "Submit" /
    >
    <
    /form> < /
    div >
  )
}
}
export default Text
```

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to call `onSubmit` method from props, having this method in child component. Instead you should call it directly on `this` object. Like this:

```
<form 
  onSubmit={this.onSubmit}>
```

Answer (score 0):

you are accessing props which is not being passed to child component, you should change the the this.props.onSubmit to this.onSubmit.

```
state = {
     title : ''
   }
  onSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.props.textChange(this.state.title);
    this.setState({ title: '' });
  };

   onChange = (e) => this.setState({ title: e.target.value });


  render() {
    return (
      <div>
      <form 
        onSubmit={this.onSubmit}>
        <input 
          type="text" 
          name="title"
          placeholder="your tex here..."
          value={this.state.title}
          onChange={this.onChange}
        />

        <input 
        type="submit"
        value ="Submit"
        />
        </form>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
export default Text
```